# Identify 4k capability from Roku user agent

Tags: user-agent, roku

I have a use case where given a Roku user agent string like "Roku/DVP-9.10 (519.10E04111A)", I want to determine whether this user agent came from a Roku device that supports 4k resolution video.

From Roku developer posts I see that **9.10** is the firmware version, and **4111** is the build. I know that Roku version 4 supports 4k, but Roku version 3 and below don't. However I don't know what part of the user agent string indicates whether the Roku device is Roku 4, Ultra, Premiere/+ or Stick + (which all support 4k). I want to filter out older Roku devices so that I don't show these older devices any 4k videos.